# How to correctly set pythonBin for serverless deploy in Github-Actions

Tags: python, github, serverless

I am attempting to deploy a simple python lambda script via github actions. I am stuck trying to figure out how to get github actions & serverless to find python3.6 (or python3.7) for a deploy.

Here is my main.yml:

```
name: Deploy Lambda

# Controls when the action will run.  on:   # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch   push:
    branches: [ master ]

# Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab   workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel jobs:   # This workflow contains a single job called "deploy"   deploy:
# The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6]
    env: #Setup environmental variables for serverless deployment
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up Python 3.6
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.6
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
          echo "which python: `which python`"
          echo "which python3.6: `which python3.6`"
      
      - name: npm install dependencies
        run: npm install
        
      - name: Serverless
        uses: serverless/github-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy
```

Here is my serverless.yml

```
service: utilitybot 

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: prod
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 128

plugins:
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-python-requirements
custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
    pythonRequirements:
      pythonBin: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.13/x64/bin/python3.6

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi_handler.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
```

And here is the relevant output when I attempt a deploy:

```
Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 aiohttp-3.7.4.post0 async-timeout-3.0.1 attrs-20.3.0 chardet-4.0.0 click-7.1.2 idna-3.1 idna-ssl-1.1.0 itsdangerous-1.1.0 multidict-5.1.0 pyee-7.0.4 slackclient-2.9.3 slackeventsapi-2.2.1 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 urllib3-1.26.4 yarl-1.6.3
which python: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.13/x64/bin/python
which python3.6: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.13/x64/bin/python3.6
. . .
Serverless: Python executable not found for "runtime": python3.6
Serverless: Using default Python executable: python
Serverless: Packaging Python WSGI handler...
Serverless: Generated requirements from /github/workspace/requirements.txt in /github/workspace/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from /github/home/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/1fc06bc3bc8373bb92e534c979ef8012825c2f0cf279b582a4c7d4a567c48e2d_slspyc/requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Using download cache directory /github/home/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc
 
 Error ---------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: python3.6 not found! Try the pythonBin option.
      at pipAcceptsSystem (/github/workspace/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:100:13)
```

I have tried no pythonBin, various versions of pythonBin, different versions of python... I cannot get past this error. When I do the which python3.6 it finds the binary in the path, so I'm confused how it doesn't appear when it does the deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working.

I changed the runtime to 3.7
I removed the python executable from pythonBin (so it is just /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.13/x64/bin/ )
I left the matrix strategy at 3.6 but had serverless install 3.7

Most importantly, I found a public image which just plain ran better:
mirrorhanyu/serverless-github-action-python@master

So the end of the main.yml becomes

```
      - name: Serverless
        uses: mirrorhanyu/serverless-github-action-python@master
        with:
          args: deploy
```